# XML invalid issue

Tags: php, .net, xml, http, cdata

I am trying to request my file which has following XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<store>

<TOS><![CDATA[STANDARD LICENSE AGREEMENT: as �the Beat�) FOR ]]> </TOS>

</store>
```

Could anybody please suggest why is this invalid?

Comment: Is your file actually UTF-8 encoded, like the header says?  What happens if you change the encoding value to "UTF-16"?

Comment: @jlew: The whole XMl becomes unreadable and I get this in browser: **㰿硭氠癥牳楯渽✱**

Comment: Actually, forget all that and see my answer below ;)

Comment: post the entire XML you cant take a snipping of it we need more.

Comment: @MaxScan: Please read my comment for jlew. The actual URl is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Save your file with UTF-8 encoding in Visual Studio.  (File | Save As | Use the dropdown on the Save button to select "Save With Encoding" and select "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001".

Comment: Sorry. I missed it. It's there. Can there be any other issues?

Comment: As for the actual URL: please visit this link: http://euphonybeats.com/_fullhosting/digitalmindsmusic/euplayer/ap/connector.php

Comment: Okay, maybe it's still an encoding problem. I'm able to paste that content into a file and save in Visual Studio, and then load it into an XDocument without problem.  It suggests that your file is not actually saved as UTF-8.  You can save as UTF-8 in Visual Studio with by choosing "Save with encoding" from thethe dropdown on the Save As dialog's Save button.  If you used notepad, for example, to save the file, it would be saved as ANSI by default, which wouldn't work right.